# Using networks in c++

Tags: c++, chat, hamachi

I have started learning c++ quite a while ago, and I am now starting to develop a program which uses a Chat file like this:

```
filename: (identity):(date)
contents: (identity):(message)
```

But the only problem I have is that I need to access and send this file over a network(A LAN created using Hamachi).

1. Do I need several libraries or something for this?
2. Can anyone give
   tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: The main part of this program is encryption using a very simple RSA method.

Comment: Do you literally mean a file? Or are you trying to exchange *messages*?

Comment: POSIX sockets API would suffice for this (if you are using unix/linux) and if performance is not at all critical you can forget about all the asynchronous mechanisms and just work with blocking socket API calls

Comment: For POSIX sockets API you need not install anything..again if working on unix/linux

Comment: If you are using Windows, see [Getting Started with Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx). If you are on Linux (or other UNIX variant) see [`man socket`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket).

Comment: There will be a chat file, which both users access and type their messages in.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of libraries which can help you:

very powerful from boost:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

one from QTNetwork (ofc if you are using QT).

I recommend you to do not use Winsock etc you will be limited to a one platform only.